# How should this Angular service be refactored so as to avoid a circular dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The $exceptionHandler service depends upon the eventBus service. Both are defined within the 'demo.services' module. Using the angular dependency injection subsystem to inject eventBus into $exceptionHandler results in a circular dependency.

I can work around this by using the $injector service to retrieve the eventBus within the $exceptionhandler factory's return function. I would rather not do this and would prefer to avoid the circular dependency if possible and inject eventBus through the angular injection subsystem. One Restriction is that I am doomed to create all services within the same module.

In short, how do I restructure my code so as to allow the Angularjs dependency injection subsytem to inject eventBus into $exceptionHandler without creating a circular dependency?

http://plnkr.co/edit/Mp9MdlS827wkrWFIF6ba?p=preview

```
/**Basic Module Dependencies, we flesh these out below**/
angular.module('demo.services',[]);
angular.module('demo.directives',['demo.services']);
angular.module('demo',['demo.services','demo.directives']);

//...See plnkr for full implementation...

/**Event Bus Service for all Intra and Inter app Messaging**/
angular.module("demo.services")
.factory("eventBus",function($window,$injector){

  var $rs = $injector.get("$rootScope");

  /*Check for our global*/
  if(!$window.$Ipp){$window.$Ipp={};}

  /*Check for event Bus*/
  if(!$window.$Ipp.eventBus){
    $window.$Ipp.eventBus =
    {
      rootScopes:[],
      test : "hello from global"
    }
  }

  /*Push our rootScope onto gloabl, we will iterate
    over that collection when we need to emit.*/
  $window.$Ipp.eventBus.rootScopes.push($rs);

  return {

    emitMsg: function(msg, data) {

      var rs=$window.$Ipp.eventBus.rootScopes;

      for(var i = 0; i < rs.length;i++){
        data = data || {}
        rs[i].$emit(msg, data);
      }

    },

    onMsg: function(msg, func, scope){
      var unbind = $rs.$on(msg, func);
      if (scope) {
          scope.$on('$destroy', unbind);
      }
    }

  }
});

/**Exception Handler Service for All JS Errors**/
angular.module('demo.services')
.factory('$exceptionHandler', function ($injector) {
    return function errorCatcherHandler(exception, cause) {
      //retrieve eventBus with injector to avoid circular dependency
      var eventBus = $injector.get('eventBus');
      eventBus.emitMsg('jsError',exception.message);
      console.error(exception);
    };
});
```

Comment: Have you considered just using angular's built in event bus provided on all scopes? It's not clear to me that your custom eventBus service does anything more than what angular provides as part of the basic framework.

Comment: Angular's event bus does not handle communication across seperate angular applications, which I must accommodate. Not shown here, but I must also communicate within Iframes as well.

Comment: Second thought: since they both look small and are already interdependent, maybe just combine them into a single common service and call it good?

Comment: I would have to replicate that for multiple services if I followed that approach. In that case I would rather just stay with 'late' resolving my dependency with $injector.